# Whether double wrapper class supports float argument?

Tags: java

As per Java tutorials, Double Wrapper class supports String and Double as argument.

But I am able to use float argument. Check below code.
Can some clarify this?

class test {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Double d=new Double(10.5f);

    Double d1=new Double("10.5f");

    System.out.println(d);  
    System.out.println(d1);

}
```

}

### Output:

10.5
  10.5

Comment: You're also able to do `double d = 10.5f;` - does that clarify things?

Answer (score 2):

Java automatically promotes float to double if needed (it's called a widening conversion).

See [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) for details

Comment: Similar to why you're able to assign an int to a long, e.g. `long a = 5`.